# I want to edit my JSON object

Tags: javascript

I have an object filled with data.

I want to add, remove, move up and move down and edit this data.

Here is an example of my object:

```
this.questions =
{
  "testQS":[
  {
  "quote": "Quote 888",
  "type": "something",
  }, {
  "quote": "Quote 999",
  "type": "something2,
  }
...
```

I have found how to do this.

To remove an item use this:

```
this.questions.testQS.splice(index, 1);
```

To swap an element use something like this:

```
const temp = this.questions.testQS[index];
this.questions.testQS[index] = this.questions.testQS[index-1];
this.questions.testQS[index-1] = temp;
```

Comment: so, i want to edit this object in Typescript

Comment: There is a difference between a JavaScript Object (what you have) and its string representation in JavaScript Object Notation (JSON, which you don't have).

Answer (score 0):

JSON is a serialized string representation of an object - so technically you just have an object in your example.

```
this.questions = {
    testQS: [
        { quote: "Quote 888", type: "something" },
        { quote: "Quote 999", type: "something2" }
    ]
};
```

You can access elements as per the below examples:

```
var allQuestions = this.questions.testQS;
var firstQuestion = this.questions.testQS[0];
var secondQuestionQuote = this.questions.testQS[1].quote;
```

If you need to perform a specific operation, you can also assign to these items just as easily.